# R packages for Durbin-Levinson algorithm and innovation algorithm for time series forecasting

Tags: math, r

I am looking for a package in R that implements the Durbin-Levinson algorithm for time series **forecasting** in $AR(p)$ model and innovation algorithm for $MA(q)$ and $ARMA(p,q)$ model.

I looked at these two packages : [ltsa](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltsa/ltsa.pdf) , [itsmr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsmr/itsmr.pdf)

However, the `TrenchForecast` function in "ltsa" package does not seem to be using the Durbin-Levinson algorithm to do forecasting. And the forecasting functions in "itsmr" does not mention that they are actually innovation algorithm to do forecasting.

Can anyone give me some suggestions where I can find R packages for these 2 algorithms or even work examples that teach me how to implement them in R ?